# ADL Testsuite 1.2.7 thowing error for Scorm 1.2 content conformance test. IE11 browse, windows8.1, JDK 1.8u45

Tags: java, javascript, argument-dependent-lookup

I tried to run SCORM content package in IE11 browser, windows 8.1 and Java runtime jdk 1.8  or 1.6 or 1.7.  none of this worked. throwing error at continue button click on selecting pif .zip file.

> Object doesn't support this property or method

```
var isValid = document.getElementById("contentPackageDriver").startValidateTest(manifestFile, testType, pifType);
```

Please help. i tried different versions and browsers even OS. but throwing same error. not able to proceed further. my content package structure is SCORM 1.2 compliance.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.... very strange though. you have to install JDK 7 update 10 or 21. but version 32-bit. (64 bit doesn't work). I have windows 8.1 64-bit and IE11. download 32 bit from http://www.neowin.net/news/java-runtime-environment-7-update-21-released